# How can I manipulate HTML elements with React and style them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, jsx, gatsby

I am currently attempting the following below.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    changeColor() {
        document.getElementbyId("test").style.color = "green";
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button id={MainStyles.test} onClick={this.changeColor} >
                Hello World
            </button>
        );
    }
}

export { MyComponent };
```

Now this works with events such as `window.alert("hello world")` but it does not work with the code above, and ends up producing this error

**"TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"**

I believe this is due to the document.getElementbyId, would `ref` fix this issue? If so how would I go about it?

Answer (score 3):

Mainstyles.test might not result in the string "test". It is impossible to know without seeing more code. Also, there is an easier way to reference the . To every function that is passed into the onClick prop, there is an event. This event is an object, and you can refactor like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    changeColor(event) {
        event.target.style.color = "green";
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={event => this.changeColor(event)} >
                Hello World
            </button>
        );
    }
}

export { MyComponent };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways in React to manipulate and style HTML elements (usually not by using *getElementbyId*, *querySelector* or any other Document methods.)

As Kasper mentions in his answer

> every function that is passed into the onClick prop, there is an event.

So you can quite easily get the target from the click event to access the HTML element.

```
import React from "react"

const MyComponent = () => {
  const changeColor = e => {
    e.target.style.color = "green"
  }
  return <button onClick={changeColor}>Hello World</button>
}

export { MyComponent }
```

---

Maybe you don't want to manipulate the button itself, but another HTML element instead. Refs might be a way of achieving this, but [the React docs suggest to avoid this if you can do it declaratively](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

```
import React, { useRef } from "react"

const MyComponent = () => {
  const myRef = useRef()

  const handleClick = () => {
    myRef.current.style.color = "green"
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Hello World</button>
      <p ref={myRef}>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export { MyComponent }
```

---

At some stage your component will reach a point where it is necessary to keep track of things using state.

In this case, we tend not to manipulate the HTML elements directly, but allow the HTML elements to be reflective of the values in our state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const MyComponent1 = () => {
  const [colorIndex, setColorIndex] = useState(0)

  const myColors = [
    "fuchsia",
    "cornflowerblue",
    "firebrick",
    "deepskyblue",
    "MediumAquamarine",
    "goldenrod",
    "OliveDrab",
    "darkmagenta",
    "orangered",
  ]

  const handleClick = () => {
    setColorIndex(colorIndex >= myColors.length - 1 ? 0 : colorIndex + 1)
  }

  return (
    <button style={{ color: myColors[colorIndex] }} onClick={handleClick}>
      Hello World
    </button>
  )
}

export { MyComponent }
```

---

If you haven't already, it might be a good time to check out the React docs, especially [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).